# Issue with imfill - Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I try to fill the object in the `BW2` but I am getting a completely white image. Why is this happening?

```
clc;
clear;
grayImage =  rgb2gray(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/afCDL.jpg'));

gaussian1 = fspecial('Gaussian', 15, 10);
gaussian2 = fspecial('Gaussian', 15, 200);
dog = gaussian1 - gaussian2;
dogFilterImage = conv2(double(grayImage), dog, 'same');

I=im2uint8(dogFilterImage); 
T = adaptthresh(I, 0.4);
BW = imbinarize(I,T);

imshowpair(I, BW, 'montage')

BW2 = bwareaopen(BW, 3000);
BW2 = imfill(BW2,'holes');
imshow(BW2)
title('Filled Image')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `conv2` uses zero-padding on the image so when you perform the convolution you're going to have a "border" around your image since you've used the `'same'` parameter.

[image]

This border is all 1's in your thresholded image causing `imfill` to completely fill in your image.

One option would be to use the `'valid'` input to `conv2` instead which will omit any pixels that are affected by the image being zero-padded prior to convolution

```
dogFilterImage = conv2(double(grayImage), dog, 'valid');
```

The other option is to explicitly pad your image with values other than zeros. You can use [`padarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html) to do this.

```
padded = padarray(double(grayImage), [8 8], 'replicate', 'both');
dogFilterImage = conv2(double(grayImage), dog, 'valid');
```

Using either of these methods your output will look like what I assume you expect.

[image]